# Hpw to allow only emoji images for contenteditable div on paste and drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I try to make my content-editable div working like Facebook, By preventing any HTML tags but accept only emoji images (not any images just images that have class .emoji) to can users submit this emojis normally.

This is the code that i used:

```
var ediv = document.getElementById("div");

function noHTML() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        var str1 = ediv.innerText.replace(/\n/g,"");

        var str2 = ediv.innerHTML.replace(/<br>/g,"");

        if (str1 != str2) {
            ediv.innerText = ediv.innerText;
        }

    }, 1);
}

ediv.addEventListener("drop", noHTML);

ediv.addEventListener("paste", noHTML);

ediv.addEventListener("copy", function(e) {
    noHTML();
    if (e.clipboardData) {
        var text = window.getSelection().toString();
        e.preventDefault();
        e.clipboardData.setData('Text', text);
    }
});

ediv.addEventListener("focus", noHTML);

ediv.addEventListener("blur", noHTML);
```

Comment: An image isn't going to have any class at all when it is dropped into your contentEditible area. The class is an HTML designation and can't be applied to elements that aren't part of the document yet.

Comment: `ediv.innerText = ediv.innerText;` is useless BTW.

Comment: @ScottMarcus So can you explain to me how Facebook make this? on Facebook you will found that you can add the smiles but can't add any anther image.

Comment: @NathanP. I try search for anther better code for this but failed, Do you have any code better than this code?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has a different approach it uses spans with unicode emojis and cover it with a span with an image to the same emoji .. but about you question I've implemented it differently .. prevent paste event to your contenteditable area and just take the text from the clipboard without any tags, and about the emojis it will only be appended from you dropdown or popover or whatever .. now you can append only emojis to your textbox but sadly you cannot copy paste it unless you figured out a way to apply a validation on pasting that only allows img tags with a specific pattern and a specific src from your server only.